# puppeteer - scrape all a->innerText

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've this part of webpage that I want to scrape href or innerText

```
<span class="hash-tag text-truncate"><a href="/url/blabla" target="_parent"><<test that i want to scrape>></a></span>
```

This is my code:

```
 const nodeChildren = await page.$$('.hash-tag', (uiElement) => {
        uiElement.map((option) => option.innerText)
    });
    console.log(nodeChildren);
```

result is:

```
_page: Page {
      eventsMap: Map(0) {},
      emitter: [Object],
      _closed: false,
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _pageBindings: Map(0) {},
      _javascriptEnabled: true,
      _workers: Map(0) {},
      _fileChooserInterceptors: Set(0) {},
      _userDragInterceptionEnabled: false,
      _handlerMap: [WeakMap],
      _client: [CDPSession],
```

How I can it?

Comment: You want `$$eval`, not `$$`. The title is misleading because you don't really want to scape all `a` inner text, you want to scrape all `.hash-tag` inner text.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const textAndHrefs = await page.$$eval(".hash-tag a", els =>
    els.map(el => ({text: el.innerText, href: el.href})))
```

Answer (score -2):

try textContent instead of innerText because it's buggy in Puppeteer.

```js
 const nodeChildren = await page.$$('.hash-tag', (uiElement) => {
        uiElement.map((option) => option.textContent)
    });
    console.log(nodeChildren);
```

Comment: What about `innerText` is buggy in Puppeteer, exactly? `innerText` runs in the browser, not Puppeteer. Also, I think you mean to use `$$eval` instead of `$$`.